# How can I use django's built-in server behind nginx?

Tags: django, nginx

I'm developing with apache2 ( mpm-worker ) + mod_wsgi behind nginx which is silly since I have to `sudo apache2ctl graceful` for every update I make in anything but the template files.

My nginx conf is:

```
server {
        listen 80; 
        server_name site.org;

        access_log /www/site.org/log/access.log;
        error_log /www/site.org/log/error.log;

        location / { 
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
                proxy_redirect off;

                proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Magic-Header "secret";
                client_max_body_size       10m;
        }

}
```

Would it be a matter of just binding `proxy_pass` to `127.0.0.1:3000` if `3000` is the port used by the django server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ack, didn't realize it was this easy... I..

- copied the `server {}` settings into another file
- changed the port to 3001
- changed the server name to `dev.site.org`
- updated my host records in the DNS to point to my server IP
- restarted nginx
- did `manage.py runserver 3001`.

All is well :)